# SQL Delete rows if 2 columns equal

Tags: sql

### I have a table like this:

| id | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 | value2 | somevalue |
| 2 | value3 | value4 | somevalue |
| 3 | value5 | value5 | somevalue |

I want to delete any rows in the table where column 2 is equal to column 3.
My table is 3000 rows long, and I want to perform this for every row that has the same value in column 2 and column 3. in this example, the row with value5 in column 2 and 3 would be deleted.

ive tried

```
DELETE FROM exampleTable t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Table t2
              WHERE t1.column2= t2.column3
              AND t2.Id = t1.Id)
```

with no success. any help would be great thank you

Comment: from same table or different table ? what is  t2?

Comment: Which DBMS you are talking about?

Comment: its the same table. im using snowflake

Comment: Am I missing something? Did you try: `DELETE FROM exampleTable WHERE column2= column3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is in the same table, it can be done way easier:

```
DELETE FROM exampleTable WHERE column2 = column3
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59f6636/1)

Comment: thank you! i was clearly ovethinking it!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you missing table name in sub query, it must like

```
SELECT * FROM [1test] t2  WHERE t2.column3 = t2.column2
```

So it will delete 3rd row, bcz column 2 and column 3 have same value.

Comment: thanks! for some reason i get the error ' invalid identifier 'T2.ID''

Comment: as u say its same table, then directly can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
delete from yourTable t1 where (select count(*) from yourTable t2 where t2.id=t1.id group by t2.id) >=2
```